# The functional equation $f(x)+f(y)=g(x+y)$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $P$ be a probability on $R$ and $f$  and $g$ two  measurable functions such that $f(x)+f(y)=g(x+y)$ almost everywhere for $P(dx)P(dy)$. How can I prove that there exist two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ almost everywhere for $P(dx)?$ It must be a classical result, but I need some references. Multiplying both sides by $e^{itx+isy} P(dx)Q(dy)$ and integrating does not lead to the solution.

Of course if $P$ has a strictly positive density with respect to the Lebesgue measure and if $g=f$ this is the classical Cauchy equation solved ages ago by Mark Kac before 1940.

Comment: $f(x)+f(y)=g(x+y)=f(x+y)+f(0)$. 

$f(x)-f(0)$ satisfies Cauchy wherever P is nontrivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $f(x+y)=g(x)+g(y) $ a.e. then functions are linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212446/show-that-if-fxy-gxgy-a-e-then-functions-are-linear)

Comment: (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%2Bf(y)%3Dg(x%2By)%24&p=1))

Comment: @AnneBauval This is pretty far from a duplicate of that question.  While that does get us, effectively, to $f=g$, it [luckily] doesn't get us over the finish line, as the more general question given here has a negative answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this is false.

For instance, let $P = \frac13(\delta_1 + \delta_\sqrt{2} + \delta_\sqrt{3})$ and $f$ be any function.

---

Note that the support $A = \{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\}$ of $P$ given here works because $|A+A| = T_{|A|}$, the $|A|$th triangular number.  This means $f(x) + f(y) = g(x+y)$ becomes trivial, as each $x+y$ is only reached one way.

Comment: There are also examples when $P$ has a density but its support is not connected.  In such cases, I think $f$ will be of the form $f(x) = ax + b(x)$ where $b(x)$ is locally constant, but the range of $b$ can be countably infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian for his penetrating comments and answer. They raised the obvious question: what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on the positive mesure $Q$ on the real line (to simplify, but the question is also natural on $R^d$) such that the solutions of the functional equation
$$f(x)+f(y)=g(x+y)$$
supposed to hold $Q$- everywhere are such that there exists $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ holds $Q$- everywhere? Quasi obvious sufficient condition is that $Q$ is concentrated on $N_0=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ or classical sufficient condition is that $Q$ has a strictly positive density with respect to the Lebesgue measure. But the general case is elusive.